# FreeNAS 9.2: install FreeBSD packages

Tags: package-management, freebsd, jails, freenas

I have installed FreeNAS 9.2amd64 (based on the same FreeBSD version) on a VirtualBox VM. I created users and pool/volume for my data.

In anticipation of installing apache/mysql-server/php5/php-myadmin FreeBSD packages, I read the following docs from the freenas.org site:

- [Installing non-PBI Software](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Installing_non-PBI_Software#Installing_FreeBSD_Packages_with_pkgng)
- [Jails](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Jails)

So I created a pluginjail to install packages within. I understood FreeNAS packages are managed by pkgng, which works almost the same than pkg_add/pkg_info/pkg_delete etc...

Then I launched the following command (don't mind the package version) from that jail shell:

```
$ pkg install mysql-server
```

And I get the following output:

```
Updating repository catalogue
pkg: PACKAGESITE/digests.txz: No address record      
pkg: No digest falling back on legacy catalog format                            
pkg: PACKAGESITE/repo.txz: No address record
```

If I go to `PACKAGESITE`, I can find both `digests.txz` and `repo.txz` files.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: PACKAGESITE=http://pkg.cdn.pcbsd.org/freenas/9.1-RELEASE/amd64/

for pkgng doc: https://wiki.freebsd.org/pkgng

Comment: The link is for 9.1 while the title says 9.2 . Which one is it?

Comment: it's 9.2 version, but there is no plugin folder for that version. That's why I put 9.1 plugins link. I don't think it is the problem. I've tried a lot of repo, I always have the same issue.

Comment: I think your only option to install things is to just unpack static compiled stuff and run them by hand. As far as I know installing custom things is just not supported on FreeNAS.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install/update your ports catalogue first. Run these commands first:

```
portsnap fetch update
 portsnap extract
```

you can then run your:

`pkg install mysql55-server` (note: it is mysql**55**-server and not mysql-server)

Comment: portsnap: Command not found.

Comment: Same problem as @LassePoulsen, how do I get portsnap?

Answer (score 1):

Install a jail and copy the necessary files from there:

```
cp /mnt/dataset>/jails/<jail-root>/etc/portsnap.conf /etc
cp /mnt/<dataset>/jails/jail-root>/usr/sbin/portsnap /usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/portsnap fetch
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` and make sure you have the correct DNS.

Comment: this was actually very useful as `portsnap` command looks through domain names for mirrors. thanks @kimo.